# why addSubview doesn't retain view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to show the backgroundView of the cell on the top of tableView when the user click a cell. But nothing is displayed. Code is as following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *v = cell.backgroundView;
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    CGRect r = [v convertRect:v.bounds toView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
    v.frame = r;
    cell.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this doesn't work because Cell is already drawn on the screen which requires a redraw to show new changes. I think you have an answer below which might solve your issue.

Comment: I just wanna change the backgroundView's parent view to self.view when click the cell

Comment: Why would you move the background view of a cell to outside the cell? It doesn't make sense. What visual effect are you aiming for?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understood that you want to show the selection of cell when user tap on cell.

For that use the delegate function of table as below

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];

        if(selectedSongIndex==[indexPath row])
        {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"lineSelected.png"];

        }

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Here I have set the image to show selection But if you want to show the color then change the background color of view.

Make sure in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function call `reload` function of table and before that set `selectedSongIndex=indexpath.row`

Comment: I'm not want to highlighted cell when selected. But make the backgroundView's parent view to be the self.view. You misunderstand me, maybe I don't expressed clearly. It's now: when I click a cell, its backgroundView disappear totally.

Answer (score 0):

addSubview  will retain  the view,
but you  make the view nil `cell.backgroundView = nil;`
so it's blank.

list out the subviews to check that

```
for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
    NSLog(@"subviews_____  %@",v );
}
```

if  you  want keep the  `cell.backgroundView`  You may use some deep copy like this:

```
 UIView *v = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cell.backgroundView]];
```

Comment: if addSubview retain the view, then cell.backgroundView = nil should not make it blank. Self.view is holding the view. Right?

Comment: I think: cell.backgroundView = nil  not mean [cell.backgroundView release] . the first one operate the pointer variable itself,the second one operate the pointer's  pointed memory area.